# jQuery - create element if doesn't exist - a shorter way

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

How can I find out if a certain element has another element as a child?
And if it doesn't, append a new one to it and then return it.

I tried it with:

```
var myel = ($('> div.my', this).length > 0)
    ? $('> div.my', this)
    : $(this).append('<div class="my"></div>').css('opacity', 0);
```

but even though it creates my element if it doesn't exist, it doesn't return it...

Comment: `$(this).children('div.my')` is faster and easier to understand than `$('> div.my', this)`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/thomas4g/rNT8k/1/

Answer (score 22, accepted):

How about this?

```
var myel = $('> div.my', this).length ? $('> div.my', this) : $('<div class="my"></div>').css('opacity', 0).appendTo(this);
```

Comment: smaller and more generic still: `var $myel = $('div#myel').length ? $('div#myel') : $('<div id="myel">');`

Answer (score 5):

This is how I would do it:

```
var myDivs = $('div.container').children('div.my');
if(myDivs.length === 0){
    myDivs = $('<div class="my"></div>   ')
        .appendTo('div.container')
        .css('opacity', 0);     
}
```

My reasoning is that you only need to query the children once, so if there is a lot of children, this will save some time.

Also, if there is no children, then you create one, `appendTo` the container, perform css and then return it.

Answer (score 3):

Similar to Alastair's method, but using filters:

```
$('div.outerDiv:not(:has(div.my))').each(function(){
  $('<div class="my"></div>')
    .appendTo(this)
    .css('opacity', 0);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Late I know, but a different approach, adding syntactic sugar and making things legible IMO:

```
function ifNotExists($x){
    if(!$x || $x.length === 0) return { create : function(newX){ return newX; }}
    else return { create : function(){ return $x } };
}

//usage:
$someDiv.append(ifNotExists("div.child").create("<div class='child'>"));
```